# How to suppress dialog/popup window of application that you have just launched from your C# code?

Tags: c#, .net, dialog, launching-application, suppress

From my C# app I'm launching annother app, which before execution sometimes show dialog/popup with some info.

Is it possible to suppress or hide this dialog and taskbar icon of the dialog ?

**EDIT**

---

Is it possible to intercept a call to the win32 function which would show this dialog and thus preventing a popup ?

Comment: Just curious what dialog/popup is showing. Is this a trial app?

Comment: Applications that were created with the intention to be lauched this way sometimes accept a `-quiet` command line parameter or alike. There is no other "normal" way to suppress dialog boxes as they are meant to pop up. There are ways, though, if you are creative, like simulate a mouse click on the active application after a certain amount of time, but nothing generic.

Comment: @eibhrum: It's an "inhouse" app without source code or any support and I need it to automate our process. But there can't be any automation if someone needs to sit behind PC and clicking on this stupid dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [FindWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) via [PInvoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.findwindow) and then send message WM_CLOSE or click Cancel button or whatever.

Comment: Do I need to perform this in a loop and constantly checking if there is window ?
Or can I react to some event ?

Comment: You would have to perform it in a loop, yes - but if it comes up when you launch the program you have a reasonably small window of time to "look" for the window so you shouldnt be looping for very long if thats a concern

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you launch this second app after your sure that your main (parent) app is fully launched and displayed its window?

Comment: My main app is just calling few other apps to do some things automaticlly. But one of this apps shows dialog which prevents this automation to work.

Comment: So cant your main app delay this launching activity?? 
May be push to loading activity into Form.Shown event method rather than if its in ctor.

Comment: What ? I think you don't understand what is my problem.

Comment: As per your explanation, your main app isnt directly dependent (tight coupled) on child apps to launch itself right? If so, y not delay that calling activity later like Form.Shown event ?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time such applications provide "Run in background (invisible)" argument that you can give when initiating them. Check whether you have such a argument.

Comment: @Primoz: You have to see the documentation of that application "Quiet", "Silent" wont' work. Sometimes may be true or false for such parameter. But you cannot guess it without looking at the documentation.